# NSTextField custom subclass and "No selection" placeholder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, user-interface, nstextfield

I have a custom `NSTextField` subclass which is bound to the property of a managed object. During its `drawRect` method it is required that I know whether the `stringValue` of the field is nil (either caused by the managed objects attribute being nil or no managed object being selected), an empty string or a "normal" string.

As far as I can tell the string value is never nil, even when the bound attribute of the managed object is nil or no managed object is selected. Am I correct or missing something?

Note: I have tried various settings in the bindings panel but this does not seem to work.

EDIT: Maybe to clarify, the effect I'm after is something as shown in Xcode when there's no selection:

[image]

The difference is, I want my "badge" to turn up when the string is an empty string (although with a slightly different message in it). I want to suppress this effect when the string is nil and use the default placeholders from the mapping panel.

Comment: Hm. Did you figure that one out.

Comment: No, unfortunately not